# how to show the shared google calendar on the app ? (php)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

i have many clients that share his calendar with me (google calendar), and i want to display the calendar on an App that i create. with the possibility of search by Email of client and than shows his calendar.
there is any possibility to do create this ?

Comment: @Bizoon both of the examples you have given are showing how to list Events,  how will this help them understand how to find a calendar that was shared with them?

Comment: @DaImTo yes but i found the solution, when we integrate the google API we have to change the ID in the code 
(Id : Email )

Comment: for my case, i have so many clients, i found the result that i want  using the DB and search method that return the ID that i searched for

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how someone shared their calendar with you you may be able to see it in the [calendarlist.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method.   The calendarlist is the list at the bottom left hand side of the google calendar web application.   THe main issue with it is that shared calendars do not always get added to this list.  If for example they shared it with a service account it will not automatically appear in the service accounts calendarlist

You could try to do a [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) and pass the users email address, now ever this will only work if the user shared their primary calendar with you.  If they shared an extra calendar that they may have created then this will return an error as you will not have access to their primary calendar.

These are your two best options the third would be asking the user to tell you the calendar id of the calendar that they shared with you.  TBH if this isn't a serie account you should have been notified by email that the calendar was shared with you.